# how to remove adsense ads on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, mobile, adsense

Does anybody how to stop showing Adsense ads on mobile devices? Recently, I activated Adsense on my blogger website. The ads were working totally fine on desktop version but on mobile devices, lots of ads started to show up. I can't even able to read the content of my website on mobile devices. I only want to show the ads on desktop devices but not on mobile. Does anybody know how to do that? The Adsense code looks something like this, I deactivated my account at this moment, so I don't have the exact code that I placed on my website. I found this code on Adsense document page - https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/181950

```js
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Homepage Leaderboard -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234567890123456"
data-ad-slot="1234567890"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Basics-for-New-Advertisers/How-to-disable-ads-for-mobile-tablet-devices/td-p/369662)?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at that article before but I couldn't able to find any setting as it was explained in the article. I think the article was talking about the Google Adwords ads, not the Adsense ads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the condition below

```
<b:if cond='data:mobile == &quot;false&quot;'>
Adsense ad code goes here..
</b:if>
```

which means "if this is not a mobile, show this ad. I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the help. As soon as my account will be activated, I will use this method. Hope you have a great day.

Comment: You're welcome, @bholaprasad
I hope your account re-activated soon